# running X on console

Tags: linux, command-line, xorg

```
Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)

 Linux 3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 12 17:08:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have downloaded a binary and ran it in the `terminal`. The binary is xflux for x86_64. It reduces the bluelight during night time.

However, when I run the binary I get this message `This will only work if you're running X on console`

All I have done is extracted the tgz and ran the binary. Everything seemed to work fine.

```
Welcome to xflux (f.lux for X)
This will only work if you're running X on console.

Found 1 screen.
Your location (lat, long) is 13.8, 100.6

Your night-time color temperature is 3400
Going to background: 'kill 9662' to turn off.
```

Just wondering about that message.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: I prefer redshift, http://jonls.dk/redshift/  It is in the repos. You should give it a try.

Comment: Redshift is good. But I would still like an answer to the above question just out of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find the source code, but I did run an strace on it. From the strace, it's clear that the `This will only work...` message is just the standard message that is printed to `stdout` before anything is actually done. Here's the important strace output:

```
write(1, "\33[2J\33[0;0f\n--------\n", 20) = 20
write(1, "Welcome to xflux (f.lux for X)\n", 31) = 31
write(1, "This will only work if you're ru"..., 52) = 52
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, 20) = 0
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, [20]) = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="mingus", ...}) = 0
access("/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority", R_OK) = 0
```

You can see that the message is printed before any attempt to access the X11 socket. Another good indication is if you run it outside of an X session; you'll see the exact same message followed by:

```
Couldn't open display (null)
```

Comment: I don't want to edit your answer, but I'd suggest that you add why X is needed. It most likely controls monitor settings through X libraries and drivers (using just pure console, this would be hard)

Answer (score 1):

I think f.lux is refering that you should start f.lux before a X (graphical) desktop.

Not sure, but maybe x needs to be a son process of your shell, like flux, and not flux from a shell interpreter opened in X